# displaying cached version of webview in android

Tags: android, html, webview, offline-caching, offline-mode

I am trying to get the HTML5 offline cached version of a website to display when the network is down inside of a webview.

I have overridden `onReceivedError` ok, and when the network is down this method is called.
Problem is that it displays the generic "Web Page is not available" message.

How can I get it to display the HTML5 cached version of the page?
The offline storage of the webapp is definately working, as it works fine in the desktop version of Firefox and Chrome.

I know I can call `loadData` into the view manually in `onReceivedError`, but im not sure where I can get the HTML5 cached value from.

Note: If I set some dummy data in `loadData` such as `view.loadData(Uri.encode("<html><div>Page load failed</div></html>"), "text/html", "UTF-8");` and then click back (by detecting back event and calling `webview.goBack();` then the cached version of the page is displayed ok.

Here are some lines of code I added to setup the webview:

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);                         
webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/com.stuff.android/cache");
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to find out the network status using

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

([Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available))

This also needs

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

Now you can set the cache behaviour either to LOAD_CACHE_ONLY or to LOAD_NO_CACHE, depending on whether a network connection is available, with

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(...)
```

Comment: this is probably the "cleanest" solution, so ill give you the bounty points :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a good solution would be to use LOAD_NORMAL and onReceivedError Navigate BACK. I think this will load the cache according to the documentation (not sure if I remember correctly) but be carefull no to get stuck in an infinite loop

---

It is weird.. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode%28int%29):

> Override the way the cache is used. The way the cache is used is based
>   on the navigation option. For a normal page load, the cache is checked
>   and content is re-validated as needed. When navigating back, content
>   is not revalidated, instead the content is just pulled from the cache.
>   This function allows the client to override this behavior.

However the behavior you want does not seem to be one of these:

1. [LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)

   > Use cache if content is there, even if expired (eg, history nav) If it is not in the cache, load from network.
2. [LOAD_CACHE_ONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ONLY)

   > Don't use the network, load from cache only.
3. [LOAD_DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ONLY)

   > Default cache usage pattern
4. [LOAD_NORMAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_NORMAL)

   > Normal cache usage pattern
5. [LOAD_NO_CACHE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_NO_CACHE)

   > Don't use the cache, load from network

---

I do not know if you can subclass the WebView to get the desired flow.

---

Comment: @Marty did you try to change LOAD_DEFAULT to LOAD_NORMAL

Comment: still just has generic "Web Page not available" message when the net connection is down when i use LOAD_NORMAL

Comment: I created a "workaround" where i load up the LOAD_NO_CACHE version, if that fails then in onReceivedError i load the LOAD_CACHE_ONLY version .. i have this working, but its quite a dodgy work around, i was hoping for a clean solution. its a bit silly it doesnt have native support for this ..

Comment: I think a good solution would be to use LOAD_NORMAL and onReceivedError Navigate BACK. I think this will load the cache according to the documentation (not sure if I remember correctly) but be carefull no to get stuck in an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Does it not work if you simply let the browser handle this?  Specify the manifest in the HTML tag like this:

```
<html manifest="mycache.appcache">
```

...and the browser should automatically use it when there's no connection available, you shouldn't need to change any settings at all.